# ExceptionInInitializerError on Itext 7

Tags: android-studio, itext7

I tried to make PDF with itext 7.2.1, this is my code:

```
    try{
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Kegiatan/" + eventName + ".pdf";

        File file = new File(path);
        file.mkdirs();

        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(file);
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document document = new Document(pdfDoc, new PageSize(612, 936).rotate());
        document.setMargins(0,0,0,0);

        //Title
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        paragraph.add(new Text(eventName).setFontSize(14).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).setBold());
        document.add(paragraph);
        document.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I got this error message, pointing at `document.close()`

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

How i can fix this?

Comment: we've noticed this issue on Android terminals with iText 7.2.1. Can you update to 7.2.2-SNAPSHOT? If not, the 7.2.2 release should come out next week with this issue fixed.

Comment: there is an error when implementing 7.2.2-SNAPSHOT. So i just gonna wait for 7.2.2. Thanks